# Filter incoming TCP packets in a web service on a PaaS environment

Tags: packet-capture, paas

Advanced Attacks Detection in a Platform-as-a-Service(PaaS) Environment

In the first part of this project, i'm supposed to monitor incoming packets
in a web service, accept only HTTP & HTTPS (TCP)packets for later analysis and, **drop the rest**.

I was thinking doing this in JAVA, because i think it's a very flexible and
complete language and, it's present in every PaaS Environment! So, my idea is 
to build a simple web page in JSP/JSF with a bean to attend this first step 
of the project.

This is where i need some guidance! Because i've started considering
**libpcap** JAVA wrappers like **jNetPcap**, **Jpcap** and **Pcap4J**. But none of them is able to drop packets!

Forgetting JAVA, i also have red about other libraries like: **libnet**, **libdnet** and **libcrafter**.

**libnet** can not handle the task! 
**libdnet** has network firewall rule manipulation capabilities, but it's a very old library and, i'm not sure it can handle integration with iptables!
**libcrafter** is the best! Because it's an actual updated project and, it allows the use of iptables rules in the code.

And, of course, working directly with **netfilter** would be the ideal scenario!

But working with **libcrafter** or **netfilter**, to follow my simple idea of a web service with a JAVA bean, i would have to write my own java wrapper by JNI! Which i assume NOT to be a simple task!

Now, what is raising many doubts in my mind, is the fact that this has to be 
done in a **PaaS environment**! None of them (PaaS providers) seem to have the
same restrictions. There are some more flexible like **AWS** and **Microsoft Azure** that let you choose and manage a VM with the OS distro you want. Others like **OpenShift**, **BlueMix** or **Cloud Foundry**, in a project, only give you the option of defining the programming language, application server and, that's it! So, one might not have permissions to install libraries and control network & transport layers to manage the packets! Since the hole OS administration is handled by the provider.

Considering only the main purpose of this project, which is **managing the packet flow pointed to a domain located in a PaaS environment**, without the help of other servers like **tcp proxies**, i am desperately in need of someone pointing me a direction to start from! Because with that, i can dig as deep as needed to get a solution. Please HELP!

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: You give a lot of detail but with completely tagging the question wrong. And the question is way to broad and offtopic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kukeltje, i'm very sorry! It was not intentional. Can you point me a better place to pose my question? Please?

Comment: Sorry, I can't since I do not have the knowledge and would have to start searching the internet for which I do not have the time. Sorry